# Sort search results by Wiki Categories, Titles, Content

Tags: search-results, enterprise-wiki

We use Office 365 SharePoint. We have several site collections, including an Enterprise Wiki, which is the primary site collection.

We want to sort search results by: Wiki Categories, Titles, Content. We want Enterprise Wiki pages prioritised over other content types.

I've set all the site collections to use an Enterprise Search Site Collection for searching. Can this be done via a Query Rule?

I'd be grateful for any advice on how to do this.
Thanks.